# VS2010 C++ Preprocessor and nested Parentheses

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, nested, c-preprocessor, parentheses

I'm defining version strings using the preprocessor in VS2010 C++. I have the following #defines:

```
#define IMPORT_VERSION_1_1                      L"IMPORT 1.0"
#define EPAPI_VERSION_1_1                       L"EPAPI 1.1"
#define EPAPI_VERSION_1_2                       L"EPAPI 1.2"
#define EPAPI_VERSION_1_3                       L"EPAPI 1.3"
#define EPAPI_VERSION_ALL_1_2                   (EPAPI_VERSION_1_2 L"," EPAPI_VERSION_1_3)
#define EPAPI_VERSION_ALL_1_2_NoParens          EPAPI_VERSION_1_2 L"," EPAPI_VERSION_1_3
#define EPAPI_VERSION_ALL_1_3                   (EPAPI_VERSION_1_3)

#define Broken                                  (EPAPI_VERSION_ALL_1_2          L"," IMPORT_VERSION_1_1)
#define Works                                   (EPAPI_VERSION_ALL_1_2_NoParens L"," IMPORT_VERSION_1_1)

const wchar_t* sJunk = Broken;
```

If I use Broken to initialise sJunk I get the following errors:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'string
>   error C2059: syntax error : ')'

If I use Works, no errors, and I get the string I'm hoping for:
`EPAPI 1.2,EPAPI 1.3,IMPORT 1.0`.

Obviously this is something to do with the nested parentheses of `EPAPI_VERSION_ALL_1_2`.  However I really don't want to remove them if I can avoid it, since side effects on non parenthesised macros are well documented.

Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to define the macro I want and keep the parens?

THanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple reason having complex results. Let us just resolve all macros:

```
Broken
(EPAPI_VERSION_ALL_1_2 L"," IMPORT_VERSION_1_1)
((EPAPI_VERSION_1_2 L"," EPAPI_VERSION_1_3) L"," L"EPAPI 1.1")
((L"EPAPI 1.2" L"," L"EPAPI 1.3") L"," L"EPAPI 1.1")
```

Your code depends on the fact that two string literals following one another get concatenated. This means we can simplify:

```
((L"EPAPI 1.2,EPAPI 1.3") L",EPAPI 1.1")
```

Now, only two string literals are left - *but they are not directly next to one another!*.

Instead, you have any old Expression (y'know, something with parenthesis) followed immediately by a string. The compiler would rather you either follow it up with an operator, or - even better - just close the other parenthesis. And this is where the compiler message comes from that it expects a `)`.

Suggested Solution:

```
#define EPAPI_VERSION_ALL_1_2 (EPAPI_VERSION_ALL_1_2_NoParens)
```

P.S.: Since this kind of string literal concatenation happens in the Lexer, this is actually pretty hard to resolve for the compiler builders ;)